# Inheritance in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

I have an abstract class that is a superclass of several components in angular2 but when I try to use the components as directives within a template it refuses to bind the properties attached to the abstract class.

but if I compile the components dynamically using Compiler in angular2 the components render fine. It also works if I use System JS with angular cli to display the page.

it only fails to run if I attempt to use Angular Cli with webpack.

Comment: If you are talking about inputs, any inputs of your super class will be erased if the child class has any inputs.

Comment: yes the components do not have any inputs its just really odd that it works when i compile it the typescript files with SystemJS it works fine but when I migrate to webpack it doesn't.